# How can I combine Azure RM resources from Azure and their billing information from the EA portal?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

Good afternoon,

I am working on a script which will output the cost of each resource in a resource group, which then will get emailed.

I have wrote the following, which connects to Azure and grabs the resources in each resource group, the output is table format like below:

Resource Name | Resource Group | Resource Type | Location

[Example table/PSObject output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7DGO.png)

This does what I want, however I would like to add the cost of the resources for the current billing month (although previous month is also fine) and not entirely sure how to do this! I have read about the UsageDetails and Billing APIs but a bit over my head, so a guided hand is appreciated!

```
    #requires -Version 3.0 -Modules ActiveDirectory, AzureRM
#Clear-Variable

function Connect-Azure
{

  Import-Module -Name AzureRM

  #Authenticate to Azure with Azure RM credentials

  Connect-AzureRmAccount

  #Select Azure Subscription
  Get-AzureRmSubscription|
  Out-GridView -PassThru|
  Set-AzureRmContext
}

Connect-Azure
$date = (Get-Date -Format d)
$ResourceGrps = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup

ForEach ($ResourceGrp in $ResourceGrps)

{
  $a = $ResourceGrp.ResourceGroupName

  $owner = 'ChevronX'

  $azureresources = Get-AzureRmResource |
  Where-Object -FilterScript {
    $_.ResourceGroupName -eq "$a" 
  } | 
  Select-Object -Property Name, ResourceGroupName, ResourceType, Location

  }
```

For the EA export I can use the following function to download the data:

```
function Get-AzureBillingUsageDetails
{
[cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(mandatory)]
        [string]$enrollmentNo,

        [parameter(mandatory)]
        [string]$accessKey
    )

    try {    

    Write-Verbose -Message "Checking Billing Period for the following Context:" -Verbose

    Write-Warning -Message "Please select Billing Period from pop up."

    $BillingPeriod = Get-AzureRmBillingPeriod | Where {$_.BillingPeriodEndDate -lt (get-date)} | Select-Object -First 1 |  Select -Property Name
    $BP = $BillingPeriod.Name

    $authHeaders = @{"authorization"="bearer $accessKey"}
    $usageUrl = "https://consumption.azure.com/v2/enrollments/$enrollmentNo/billingPeriods/$BP/usagedetails"

    Write-Verbose -Message "URL: $usageUrl" -Verbose
    Write-Verbose -Message "Selected Month, Billing Period: $BillingPeriod" -Verbose
    Write-Verbose -Message "Polling for Data, please wait..." -Verbose

        while ($usageUrl -ne $null) #1000 lines of usage data returned per request
        {
            $usagedetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $usageUrl -Headers $authHeaders -ErrorAction Stop -Method GET
            $usagedetails.data
            $usageUrl = $usagedetails.nextLink
        }
    Write-Verbose -Message "Completed Polling for Data" -Verbose
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Warning $_
    }
}#Get-AzureBillUsageDetails
```

And:

```
}#Get-AzureBillUsageDetails

function Get-AzureBillingMonthlySummary
{
 param (
        $usage,
    $Filter = '.'
)

end{
    [double]$gtotal = 0
    $usage | group resourcegroup | sort Name -Descending |
    Where Name -match $Filter |
    foreach-object {

    $g = $_.group
    $total = ($g | measure -Property cost -Sum | foreach Sum)

    $tags = ConvertFrom-Json $g[0].tags



        [pscustomobject]@{
         ResourceGroup    = $g[0].resourceGroup
            SubscriptionName = $g[0].subscriptionName

               BillTo       = $tags.BillTo
            'Application Owner' = $tags.'Application Owner'
            'Reference Name'      = $tags.'Reference Name'
            Environment = $tags.Environment
          #  DepartmentId     = $g[0].departmentId
            TotalCost        = "{0:C}" -f $total
    }

        $gtotal += $total
    }#Foreach-Object
Write-Verbose "Total is: $gtotal" -Verbose
}#End

}
```

I want to grab the tags from the Resource Group directly in Azure as they are up to date and there are some Resource Groups with resources that don't support tagging. Its frustrating me, as I don't understand it enough to be able to merge the data together! Hoping someone can assist me take it further and combine it.

--

11/12/18 - Script after using Join-Object

```
       $azureresources = Get-AzureRmResource |
        Where-Object -FilterScript {
        $_.ResourceGroupName -eq "$a"
    } |
        Select-Object -Property Name, ResourceGroupName, ResourceType, Location, ResourceId

       $report =  Join-Object -Left $azureresources -Right $usage -LeftJoinProperty 'ResourceId' -RightJoinProperty 'instanceId' -Type AllInLeft -RightProperties 'cost'

 $ourObject = @()
ForEach ($resource in $report)


{

 $resourcecost = ($report.cost |  measure -Sum | foreach Sum)

             $ourObject+= [pscustomobject] @{

'Resource Name' =  $resource.Name
'Resource Group'  =  $resource.ResourceGroupName
'Resource Type'  =  $resource.ResourceType
'Resource Cost'  =  "{0:C}" -f  $resourcecost


}

}
```

[Current script output - duplication of resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uusqw.png)

Comment: I'd merge on resourceId

Comment: That actually sounds what I want to do, are you able to give me a workable example? Is it something like: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join/2.3.0

Comment: no sorry, thats a bit too much for one question\answer

Comment: Thanks - It is getting close. I ended up added the 'Join-Object' function. However now I am ending up with multiple resources, that exist in $report (for some reason) and the resource costs are not aligning to the resources, do you or anyone have any suggestions on fixing this and selecting only the unique resources from $azureresources. My current script is now looking like the following:

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can try *select -unique*, to filter out duplicates.

But it would be much more productive if you could share some sample datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help/suggestions! Managed to sort it out.
Thanks to '4c74356b41' comment - managed to use the Join-Object function (http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object/) to merge the data together. Just had to use the Join-Object with the option '-Type OnlyIfInBoth' to get rid of the duplicates!